# Codeigniter get controller name in helper

Tags: codeigniter

I have a custom helper that i use for logging.

Within one of the functions of the helper i need to get the name of the controller that was called. Is there a way to do it?

I can't rely on uri segments because some controllers are in sub-folders and the helper is used all over.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the following in CI2.x

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
```

You may need to get an instance of the CI super variable $this first- in which case. Use the following:

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->router->fetch_class();
```

There's also a `$ci->router->fetch_method();` method if you need the name of the method called for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->>router->fetch_method();` will return `index` if you do something like this:

```
class Someclass extends CI_Controller {        
    function index(){        
        $this->edit();        
    }        
    function edit(){        
        $this->router->fetch_method(); //outputs index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work (not so sure if it works in the helper):

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->router->class // gets class name (controller)
$ci->router->method // gets function name (controller function)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the URI class

```
$ci = & get_instance();
$ci->uri->segment(1) // That stands for controller
$ci->uri->segment(2) // That stands for method
```