# Code Igniter get name of model instance that created object?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, instance

I am using CodeIgniter and have extended `CI_Model`. so all my models now extend `MY_Model`.

This works fine.

Issue is that all my models have a secondary associated object. basically a class that gets passed data from the model (usually from the database) and represents that row in the database.

so something like

```
class Product_Model extends MY_Model{
    public function get($id){
        //....
        return new Product($query->row()); 
    }
}


class Product{

    public function __construct(stdClass $data){
      //....
      self::$ci =& get_instance();
      self::$model = self::$ci->products;
    }

}
```

Now I load the Product_Model with an alias `$this->load->model('product_model', 'products');`

Hence having `self::$model = self::$ci->products;`

But now I want to have a basic class that all the classes like `Product` will extend.

I want this to contain the logic to update `self::$model`.

But I need to know the models alias.

Something like

`self::$model = self::$ci->{instantiator_variable_name($this)}` which would be `self::$model = self::$ci->products`

Now obviously that function does not exist but it shows what I want to do.

I know I could for everywhere that I create the `Product` or similar have

```
$row = $query->row();
$row->model = $this->ci->products;
return new Product($row);
```

But I would rather automate it if I could.

Comment: it sounds like you're looking to implement a factory pattern in your development, which is very common in framework development.

Comment: This answer should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8168711/540001

Comment: @beardedlinuxgeek I don't think the router class actually has a method like that for models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you clarify the situation a bit. Post a bit more of your code please?

For example, Modals (in CodeIgniter) are generally used as singleton classes which (almost) explains using 'self::" but it looks like you want Product to be an Object. So why does that use

```
self::$model
```

instead of

```
$this->model
```

The fact that you're aliasing the products model makes me think you might be doing this on purpose (which is why I'm confused, why would you do this?). I think you should review the difference between "self::", "static::", and "$this->". Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

rockstarz is correct, you need to use the Factory Pattern. Consider something like this:

```
class ItemFactory {

    private $model;

    public function __construct($model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    function create_product(stdClass $data) {
        $product = new Product($data);
        $product->set_model($this->model);
        return $product
    }
}

abstract class Item {

    protected $model;
    protected $ci = & get_instance();

    public function __construct(stdClass $data) {
        // whatever
    }

    public function set_model($model) {
        $this->$model = $model;
    }

    public function get_model() {
        return $this->model;
    }

}

class Product extends Item {
    // whatever
}
```

Then your model can just use it like

```
class Product_Model extends MY_Model {

    private $item_factory;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->item_factory = new ItemFactory($this);
    }

    public function get($id){
        return $this->item_factory->create_product($row);
    }

}
```

Relevant reading materials:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control#Implementation_techniques

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: Ah yes, I should have mentioned, the reason that I am storing `$ci` and `$model` as static members is because I don't want them printed out in my debugging basically, `var_dump` and `print_r` exclude static members.